# VB TicTacToe StackOverFlow

Tags: vb.net, tic-tac-toe

I am trying to create a Tic Tac Toe game in VB but I keep getting an error:

> StackOverflowExpeption was unhandled

I have checked my code and watched many tutorials, still can't figure out what is wrong, here is the code:

```
Public Class TicTac

Private intSet As Integer = 0 'Movimentos que podes fazer

Private Sub btnReset_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReset.Click

    btn1.Text = ""
    btn1.Enabled = True
    btn2.Text = ""
    btn2.Enabled = True
    btn3.Text = ""
    btn3.Enabled = True
    btn4.Text = ""
    btn4.Enabled = True
    btn5.Text = ""
    btn5.Enabled = True
    btn6.Text = ""
    btn6.Enabled = True
    btn7.Text = ""
    btn7.Enabled = True
    btn8.Text = ""
    btn8.Enabled = True
    btn9.Text = ""
    btn9.Enabled = True

End Sub

'formulário
Private Sub TicTac_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    btn1.Text = ""
    btn1.Enabled = True
    btn2.Text = ""
    btn2.Enabled = True
    btn3.Text = ""
    btn3.Enabled = True
    btn4.Text = ""
    btn4.Enabled = True
    btn5.Text = ""
    btn5.Enabled = True
    btn6.Text = ""
    btn6.Enabled = True
    btn7.Text = ""
    btn7.Enabled = True
    btn8.Text = ""
    btn8.Enabled = True
    btn9.Text = ""
    btn9.Enabled = True

    intSet = 0

End Sub

Sub ComputerPlays()

    Dim objRandom As New Random
    Dim intRandom As Integer

    intRandom = objRandom.Next(1, 10)

    If intRandom = 1 And btn1.Enabled = True Then
        btn1.Text = "O"
        btn1.Enabled = False
        Exit Sub

    End If

    If intRandom = 2 And btn2.Enabled = True Then
        btn2.Text = "O"
        btn2.Enabled = False
        Exit Sub

    End If

    If intRandom = 3 And btn3.Enabled = True Then
        btn3.Text = "O"
        btn3.Enabled = False
        Exit Sub

    End If

    If intRandom = 4 And btn4.Enabled = True Then
        btn4.Text = "O"
        btn4.Enabled = False
        Exit Sub

    End If

    If intRandom = 5 And btn5.Enabled = True Then
        btn5.Text = "O"
        btn5.Enabled = False
        Exit Sub

    End If

    If intRandom = 6 And btn6.Enabled = True Then
        btn6.Text = "O"
        btn6.Enabled = False
        Exit Sub

    End If

    If intRandom = 7 And btn7.Enabled = True Then
        btn7.Text = "O"
        btn7.Enabled = False
        Exit Sub

    End If

    If intRandom = 8 And btn8.Enabled = True Then
        btn8.Text = "O"
        btn8.Enabled = False
        Exit Sub

    End If

    If intRandom = 9 And btn9.Enabled = True Then
        btn9.Text = "O"
        btn9.Enabled = False
        Exit Sub

    End If

    ComputerPlays()

End Sub

Private Sub MyPlays(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click, btn2.Click, btn3.Click, btn4.Click, btn5.Click, btn6.Click, btn7.Click, btn8.Click, btn9.Click
    'As jogadas do Utilizador

    sender.text = "X"
    sender.enabled = False
    intSet += 1

    CheckVencedor()

    'AS Jogadas do PC
    ComputerPlays()

    intSet += 1

    CheckVencedor()

End Sub

Sub CheckVencedor()

    If intSet >= 9 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Ninguém ganhou")
    ElseIf btn1.Text = "O" And btn2.Text = "O" And btn3.Text = "O" Or
           btn4.Text = "O" And btn5.Text = "O" And btn6.Text = "O" Or
           btn7.Text = "O" And btn8.Text = "O" And btn9.Text = "O" Or
           btn1.Text = "O" And btn4.Text = "O" And btn7.Text = "O" Or
           btn2.Text = "O" And btn5.Text = "O" And btn8.Text = "O" Or
           btn3.Text = "O" And btn6.Text = "O" And btn9.Text = "O" Or
           btn1.Text = "O" And btn5.Text = "O" And btn9.Text = "O" Or
           btn7.Text = "O" And btn5.Text = "O" And btn3.Text = "O" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Computador ganhou, perdestes seu scrub!")

    ElseIf btn1.Text = "X" And btn2.Text = "X" And btn3.Text = "O" Or
       btn4.Text = "X" And btn5.Text = "X" And btn6.Text = "O" Or
       btn7.Text = "X" And btn8.Text = "X" And btn9.Text = "O" Or
       btn1.Text = "X" And btn4.Text = "X" And btn7.Text = "O" Or
       btn2.Text = "X" And btn5.Text = "X" And btn8.Text = "O" Or
       btn3.Text = "X" And btn6.Text = "X" And btn9.Text = "O" Or
       btn1.Text = "X" And btn5.Text = "X" And btn9.Text = "O" Or
       btn7.Text = "X" And btn5.Text = "X" And btn3.Text = "O" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Wow, ganhastes seu noob!")
    End If

End Sub

End Class
```

Sometimes, the game works but it keeps crashing.

Comment: For debugging questions, you need to include the error message/stack trace (copy and paste it) in your question.

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: @LarsTech line 54 Sub ComputerPlays()               System.StackOverflowException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147023895
  Message=Tipo de excepção 'System.StackOverflowException' accionado.
  InnerException:

Comment: Oh, sure, there it is.  ComputerPlays is calling ComputerPlays.  Obviously, remove that line.  I would move that Random declaration outside of that scope so it's only initialized once.

Comment: Oh how did i missed that, yeah now its working well, just need to change a few things thx alot :D